# return offset of a string with lua

Tags: string, lua, find, return, offset

I'm trying to search rather big files for a certain string and return its offset. I'm new to lua and my current approach would look like this:

```
linenumber = 0
for line in io.lines(filepath) do
result=string.find(line,"ABC",1)
linenumber = linenumber+1

if result ~= nil then
offset=linenumber*4096+result
io.close
end
end
```

I realize that this way is rather primitive and certainly slow. How could I do this more efficiently?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is not too big, and you can spare the memory, it's faster to just slurp in the whole file and just use `string.find`. If not you can search the file by block.

Your approach isn't all that bad. I'd suggest loading the file in overlapping blocks though. The overlap avoids having the pattern split just between the blocks and going unnoticed like:

```
".... ...A BC.. ...."
```

My implementation goes like this:

```
size=4096 -- note, size should be bigger than the length of pat to work.
pat="ABC"
overlap=#pat
fh=io.open(filepath,'rb') -- On windows, do NOT forget the b
block=fh:read(size+overlap)
n=0
while block do
    block_offset=block:find(pat)
    if block_offset then
        print(block_offset)
        offset=block_offset+size*n
        break
    end
    fh:seek('cur',-overlap)
    cur=fh:seek'cur'
    block=fh:read(size+overlap)
    n=n+1
end

if offset then
    print('found pattern at', offset, 'after reading',n,'blocks')
else
    print('did not find pattern')
end
```

If your file really has lines, you can also use the trick explained [here](http://www.lua.org/pil/21.2.1.html). [This section](http://www.lua.org/pil/21.1.html) in the Programming in Lua book explains some performance considerations reading files.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your example! It works like a charm. I worked my way through section 21.1. of the lua code book before posting my question, but I missed 21.2.1, so thanks for the hint!

I'm not familiar with the concept of the "#"-symbol yet. Apparently you used it to create the overlap, but is there a section in the lua code book that explains its usage in detail and its features such as overlap size?

Comment: The `#` operator simply returns the length of strings, tables that are sequences (keys are 1 to n, without holes) or objects which define a __len metamethod. Do note that the length of strings is the number of *bytes*, which is not necessarily equal to the number of characters (think UTF-8 and the like).

Answer (score 1):

Unless your lines have all the same lenght (4096), I don't see how your code can work.

Instead of using `io.lines`, read blocks with `io.read(4096)`. The rest of your code can be used as is, except that you need to handle the case that your string is not fully inside a block. If the files is composed of lines, then a trick mentioned in Programming in Lua is to do `io.read(4096,"*l")`, to read blocks that end at line boundaries. Then you don't have to worry about strings not fully inside a block but you need to adjust the offset calculation to include the length of the block, not just 4096.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I parsed the io.lines-reading behaviour with process monitor and it showed that the file was read in 4096byte chunks, so I assumed that was the standard value for io.lines. You're solution set me straight. Thanks again!