# How to find word from the end of file in Lua

Tags: file, lua

Ok I use method from here: [How to Read only the last line of a text file in Lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497311/how-to-read-only-the-last-line-of-a-text-file-in-lua)

The problem is that sometimes line can be bigger.

The question is how can i find first word "foo" from the end of file and then use everything after it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that sometimes line can be bigger.

Then you just need to seek further back from the end.

> The question is how can i find first word "foo" from the end of file and then use everything after it?

Grab a big enough chunk of the file to be sure you've got the last foo, the use `.*foo` to skip everything up to and including the last "foo" (.* is greedy).

```
local f = io.open('filename', 'r')
f:seek('end', -1024)
local text = f:read('*a')
local after = string.match(text, ".*foo(.*)")
f:close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file is not too big and you're ready to take the easy way out this might help:

```
fh=io.open('myfile.txt','rb')
str=fh:read'*a'
pat='foo'
afterFoo=str:match('.*'..pat..'(.*)$')
fh:close()
```

If you need a more complex, but faster (in run time on large files) solution, my guess would be that you' read in the file in chunks, reverse each of them, and look for your pattern in reverse. Don't forget to look for your pattern across the borders (the chunks must overlap at least the length of the pattern you're seeking in the general case).

For more explanation about the block reading, see my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907949/return-offset-of-a-string-with-lua/8908677#8908677).

Comment: Thank you too, my file can be very big (I am parsing a log).

Comment: Given that you're already using a regular expression, there's no need to reverse anything. Just use `.*PATTERN` to skip everything up to and including the last occurrence of `PATTERN`.